# How do I write a CakePHP find() condition with mixed AND OR operators?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I read in the CakePHP 1.3 documentation that the `conditions` parameter for `find()` is equivalent to the SQL `WHERE` clause.  I'm trying to write something like this in CakePHP:

```
 select count(*) from claim 
 where ((claim_id = X and company_id = W) or (claimant_firstName = Y and claimant_lastName = Z))
```

However, I am confused about how to structure the `conditions` parameter.

Is it like

```
 find('count', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                              Claim.company_id => $companyId,
                              Claim.id' => $claimNumber,
                             'or' => array(
                                     'Claimant.first_name' => $claimantFirstName,
                                     'Claimant.last_name' => $claimantLastName,
                                     )
                           )
              )
     );
```

or

```
     find('count', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                             'or' => array(
                                        Claim.company_id => $companyId,
                                        Claim.id' => $claimNumber
                                     )
                             'or' => array(
                                     'Claimant.first_name' => $claimantFirstName,
                                     'Claimant.last_name' => $claimantLastName,
                                     )
                           )
              )
```

or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $conditions =  array(
                   'or' => array ( 
                       array( 'and' => array( 'Claim.company_id' => $companyId, 'Claim.id' => $claimNumber )), 
                       array( 'and' => array( 'Claimant.first_name' => $claimantFirstName, 'Claimant.last_name' => $claimantLastName )) 
                   )
                 );
  $this->ModelName->find('count', array( 'conditions' => $conditions ));
```

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to do what I want.